# Oracle OLE DB - Connection string without password

Tags: oracle, vbscript, oledb

I'm working on programmatic queries relying on the Oracle provider for OLE DB (in VB script).

I can successfully query my database using the standard syntax: *Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=MyOracleDB;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;*

But how can I make it work **without disclosing the password**? 
I have Oracle Wallet running on my server. How could I integrate it with my script?
Any other idea?

OS authentication won't work here.

Thank you very much in advance for your suggestions.

Best,

Alexis